initState vs didChangeDependencies in using context
as I was studying the lifecycle of a stateful widget I found that we can not use the context in the initState because the context is not totally inserted to the widget tree,
however when I use the BlocProvider.of(context) it works with me and I don't know why here is the full code :
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    LoadingCubit.get(context).loadingState();
    getParticipatedEvents()
        .then((value) {
      events = value;
      LoadingCubit.get(context).notLoadingState();
    })
        .catchError((e) {
      LoadingCubit.get(context).notLoadingState();
      Navigator.pop(context);
      errorHandler(context, e: e);
    });
  }

the above code works well, anyone knows why ?
secondly,  the didChangeDependencies is called whenever a dependency of the widget is change what does that mean ? and it's at least called one after the initState is called what are the dependencies that are changed at that time ?
thanks in advance for the help .
